# Java mock objects inside resource

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, dropwizard

I'm using the Dropwizard framework and I'm trying to mock certain objects inside a web resource (the web resource tries to communicate with something external and I want to mock that).

Currently, I'm running the Dropwizard application in my tests through:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.apache.http.conn.ssl.*", "javax.net.ssl.*", "javax.crypto.*", "javax.management.*", "javax.net.*"})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ ExternalCommunicator.class})
public class MockTest {
    @ClassRule
    public static final DropwizardAppRule<ApplicationWebserviceConfiguration> RULE = new DropwizardAppRule<>(ApplicationWebserviceApplication.class, ResourceHelpers.resourceFilePath("config.yml"));
    @Before 
    public void doStuff() {
        final ExternalCommunicator externalCommunicator = mock(ExternalCommunicator.class);    
        whenNew(ExternalCommunicator.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(externalCommunicator);
}
```

My resource looks something like:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Timed
@UnitOfWork
@ApiOperation(value = "Talk to things", notes = "Talk to things.", response = String.class)
public String talk(@ApiParam(value = "id", required = true) @PathParam("id") Long id) {
    ExternalCommunicator communicator = new ExternalCommunicator(id);
    String result = communicator.get();
    someDAO.create(result);
    return result;
}
```

I'm using powermock and mockito but can't seem to correctly mock ExternalCommunicator

I've also tried

```
@Rule
public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
```

instead of @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) annotation but that doesn't seem to work either

Additionally, I do not want to mock the DAO.

Comment: You can't mock parts of method body, you need to externalize creation of communicator somehow. For example, if you have method `createCommunicator(id)`, then this is the method you mock to achieve what you want.

Comment: I agree with @M.Prokhorov - you won't be able to effectively mock `ExternalCommunicator` until you are no longer creating a new one directly in `talk` with the `new` keyword.

Comment: You did not post a complete test-case or your resource implementation, but as per the [docs](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockconstructor), the class that you need to prepare for test when mocking constructors, is actually the class that normally creates the new instance. So in your case, instead of `@PrepareForTest({ ExternalCommunicator.class})` try `@PrepareForTest({ MyResource.class})`.